# Spring OAuth2 Resource allowed only for clients and token auto creation

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, oauth, spring-security-oauth2

I have an App that is using `OAuth2` `password` `grant type` to manage the user authorizations to his resources. All App resources are only allowed access for a client with once provided token to act on behalf of some user, except the URI to create users, this one I want that only authenticaed clients have access to it. I'm using spring-security-oauth2 as my OAuth implementation and but can't figure out how to accomplish this in a less hacky way than the one described bellow:

`POST /users` to be acessed only by authenticated clients.

Currently I figured out how to this by removing `@EnableAuthorizationServer` and creating a new class and extending `AuthorizationServerSecurityConfiguration` class and overriding method: `configure( HttpSecurity http )` and creating a new `@Configuration` class and `@Import` `AuthorizationServerEndpointsConfiguration` and  `CustomAuthorizationServerSecurityConfiguration`.
The problem is that, in my new custom `class` I need to override and copy/paste the entire method original code in the overrided method, ending with something like:

`@Override
    protected void configure( HttpSecurity http ) throws Exception {
      AuthorizationServerSecurityConfigurer configurer = new AuthorizationServerSecurityConfigurer();
      FrameworkEndpointHandlerMapping handlerMapping = endpoints.oauth2EndpointHandlerMapping();
      http.setSharedObject(FrameworkEndpointHandlerMapping.class, handlerMapping);
      configure(configurer);
      http.apply(configurer);
      String tokenEndpointPath = handlerMapping.getServletPath("/oauth/token");
      String tokenKeyPath = handlerMapping.getServletPath("/oauth/token_key");
      String checkTokenPath = handlerMapping.getServletPath("/oauth/check_token");
      http
            .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers(tokenEndpointPath).fullyAuthenticated()
                .antMatchers( HttpMethod.POST, "/users/**").fullyAuthenticated()
                .antMatchers(tokenKeyPath).access(configurer.getTokenKeyAccess())
                .antMatchers(checkTokenPath).access(configurer.getCheckTokenAccess())
          .and()
            .requestMatchers()
              .requestMatchers( new AntPathRequestMatcher(tokenKeyPath), 
                                new AntPathRequestMatcher(tokenEndpointPath), 
                                new AntPathRequestMatcher(checkTokenPath),
                                new AntPathRequestMatcher("/users/**", HttpMethod.POST.name()));
      http.setSharedObject(ClientDetailsService.class, clientDetailsService);
    }`

My first question is, the a better way to do this?

The second thing that I want to do is to auto create the AccessToken by password grant type when a new user is created (in the URI `POST /users`), and I can't figure any way to do this.

Can someone provide any insight on this two needs?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is what you are asking but what I understad is that you want
   to configure specific security constrains for request on /users endpoint with POST method. so
   this is how I would do this.I do not think that extending
   `AuthorizationServerSecurityConfiguration` is neccesary since recomended way
   is usually to extend just `WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter` in your main
  security config class, remember that you can configure your HttpSecurity multiple times for multiple endpoints, but if you configure the same endpoint in multiple places the last configuration read will be the one active

```
           @EnableWebSecurity public class SecurityConfiguration extends
           WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
           //other methods ...

           @Override
           @Bean 
           public AuthenticationManager authenticationManagerBean() throws
           Exception { 
              return super.authenticationManagerBean();
           }

           @Order(1)
           @Override 
           protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {  
                //configure your path here
                //I purposly configured GET user to
                // permit all to see diference
                //for example
                // @formatter:off
                http
                .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers(HttpMethod.GET,"/user")
                .permitAll() 
                .antMatchers(HttpMethod.POST,"/user")
                .fullyAuthenticated()
                .and().csrf().disable()
                .formLogin();
                // @formatter:on
            }

       }
```

and then in your Ouath configuration

```
@Configuration
public class OAuth2ServerConfiguration {

    private static final String RESOURCE_ID = "restservice";

    @Configuration
    @EnableResourceServer
    protected static class ResourceServerConfiguration extends ResourceServerConfigurerAdapter {

        @Override
        public void configure(ResourceServerSecurityConfigurer resources) {
            // @formatter:off
            resources
                .resourceId(RESOURCE_ID);
            // @formatter:on
        }

        @Override
        public void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
            // @formatter:off
             http
                .requestMatchers()
                .antMatchers("/resources/**","/greeting")
                .and() 
                .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/resources").access("#oauth2.hasScope('read') or hasRole('ROLE_USER')")
                .antMatchers("/greeting").access("#oauth2.hasScope('read')"); 
            }
    }

    @Configuration
    @EnableAuthorizationServer
    protected static class AuthorizationServerConfiguration extends AuthorizationServerConfigurerAdapter {

        private TokenStore tokenStore = new InMemoryTokenStore();

        @Autowired
        @Qualifier("authenticationManagerBean")
        private AuthenticationManager authenticationManager;

        @Override
        public void configure(AuthorizationServerEndpointsConfigurer endpoints) throws Exception {
            // @formatter:off
            endpoints
                .tokenStore(this.tokenStore)
                .authenticationManager(authenticationManager);
                // @formatter:on
        }

        @Override
        public void configure(ClientDetailsServiceConfigurer clients) throws Exception {
            // @formatter:off
            clients
                .inMemory()
                    .withClient("clientapp")
                        .authorizedGrantTypes("password","refresh_token")
                        .authorities("USER")
                        .scopes("read", "write")
                        .resourceIds(RESOURCE_ID)
                        .secret("123456");
            // @formatter:on

        }

        @Bean
        @Primary
        public DefaultTokenServices tokenServices() {
            DefaultTokenServices tokenServices = new DefaultTokenServices();
            tokenServices.setSupportRefreshToken(true);
            tokenServices.setTokenStore(this.tokenStore);
            return tokenServices;
        }

    }

}
```

As you can see above `HttpSecurity` is conconfigured twice once in class that extends `WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter` and also in your class extending`ResourceServerConfigurerAdapter` for your Ouath configuration

part of this example is taken from this gitHub example by royclarkson
https://github.com/royclarkson/spring-rest-service-oauth

I am not sure what you are asking about in your second question, could you clarify ?

Comment: take a look in this thread: [Github](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security-oauth/issues/377#issuecomment-71651468), I posted the same question there and the discussion will clear up my need to you. And my second question is how I create a token for an user by the `password grant type` flow in the `/users` resource, in other words I need to generate the  OAuth2AccessToken in the `/users`, do you know some simple strategy to do that?

Comment: if you posted your configure `ClientDetailsServiceConfigurer ` configuration, it might be easier, I looked at your git hub and I still do not understand why you configure it this way, dsyer gave you pretty much the same solution as I gave you above, create different endpoint /user with its own security constrains and in that endpoint obtain token internally and return it to user in JSON format  if this what you want to return

Comment: In the post above I added `DefaultTokenServices` you can obtain token from it if you provide `OAuth2Authentication` object not sure if this is appropriate to mix this stuff with the controller but its a Bean and you can autowire it

Comment: user1289300 as you have seen in my last comment on Github, I gave up on my custom configuration and I will use the `client_credentials` grant type to accomplish the definition and protection of `/users` resources only to clients. In relation with your suggestion about `DefaultTokenService` I will give a try, thanks!

Comment: I managed to make work the token generation from `DefaultTokenServices`, thanks for the help, I will not mark your answer as correct because in my case the best solution was to use `client_credentials` flow to protect `/users` resource, ok!? I will share my solution to make things more clear. Thanks again.